# Zoom too big on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm having a problem with my site. On Chrome/IE it looks ok, but on Firefox it's way too zoomed on default (the zoom is theoreticaly 100% in the browser).

This is the website: http://pascaru.pl/horizontal2/index-6.html

I've read that this can have something to do with fonts, so I changed all em to px, but no change.

I removed all styles for a moment to check if that helps, but it's still way bigger on Firefox.

In my html I have this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

and it's still too big on FF.

What else can I do to have it the same size on all browsers?

Comment: I see the same in Firefox and Chrome. Maybe is a stupid question but, you have set the default zoom in Firefox? `Ctrl + 0`

Comment: @blonfu no stupid question, but yes, I did :) Thanks for checking!

Comment: @blonfu what Firefox are you using btw?

Comment: Firefox 47 in windows 7